# What is the right way to inflate an ActionBar custom view?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a custom layouts for my Action bar, so I'm inflating it with the following code:

```
        final ViewGroup actionBarLayout = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
            R.layout.action_bar_mailbox, null);

    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setCustomView(actionBarLayout);
```

Although this seems to work fine, I know that passing null as view root is not recommended. What is the proper way to inflate this layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Although this seems to work fine, I know that passing null as view
>   root is not recommended. What is the proper way to inflate this
>   layout?

it's ok to pass null. The container is used by the system to copy some parameters (`LayoutParameters`)